# How to scroll inside a div inside a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

My goal is to scroll inside a div with the scroll bar on the entire page. In the first image, I have the scroll bar because the text inside the div is long. But, in the second image, the scroll bar goes away when I put all the text inside the div. Is there a way to keep text inside the div and have the scroll bar on the right?

```
.background {
  background-color: #1A1A1A;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 300px;
}

#information{
  height: 400px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FEC12E;

  overflow-y: hidden;

  /* shadow */
  box-shadow: 5px 4px 18px #FEC12E;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: is #information your div?  if so you need to allow overflow-y: scroll to see the scrollbar, but this will make the scrollbar apply to the div, not to the parent container (which im guessing is the body).

Comment: You probably want to make a custom scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got a mock close to what you want.

This will require the use of jquery because I'm lazy and makes this operation loads easier (sorry if thats a problem).

Here is a mockup:

https://jsfiddle.net/pksqkm50/7/

```js
let b = $(document);
let d = $('#yourdiv');
let scrollamt = 0;
b.on('wheel', function(e) {
    if((scrollamt <= d[0].scrollHeight - d[0].offsetHeight) && (b.scrollTop() == 0)){
        e.preventDefault();
    } else{
        scrollamt = d[0].scrollHeight - d[0].offsetHeight;
        return;
    }
    scrollamt < 0 ? scrollamt = 0 : null;
    e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0 ? scrollamt +=100 : scrollamt -=100;
    d.animate({
       scrollTop: scrollamt
    },50);
})
```

```css
body{
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#yourdiv{
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="yourdiv">
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</div>
<div>
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</div>
<div>
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</div>
<div>
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Simon, I appreciate your help so much. I just went online to check it, and it seems exactly what I needed help with. I’ll try to integrate it with what I’m doing. When it works I’ll select your response as the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I updated code to what I think you want.  It should handle what you are describing I think.  If you dont want to display scrollbars, change the css, but they should always display and act the way you want them.

Comment: It worked. I wish I could better understand what you did there. Going to read it many times to understand it better! Thanks.

Comment: Code reads in english:  Start a number at 0.  When user uses mouse wheel, is the number we set initially still less than the potential length of the orange divs scrollbar AND is the scrollbar of the red document at the top?  Then ignore how scrolling usually works, otherwise, get out of this function because we still want other things to scroll normally and go ahead and set the number to the maximum value of the orange divs scroll potential.  If we didn't get out of the function, manage incrementing or decrementing the number, and then use the number to animate the scrolling of the orange div.

Comment: You may notice that scrolling of the orange div seems a little quirky, because there is no easing applied to the scrolling.  It is merely incrementing the scrollbars position by 100 pixels each scroll event.  If you wish to simulate how browsers ease scrolling, that is a more in depth thing but you can read about it here with jquery: http://api.jquery.com/animate/#easing

Comment: Thank you Simon. You are being tremendously helpful.

Comment: Only reason I can answer you better than others, is because I've done this sort of behavior before for a chat application which required the thing to have several scrolling capabilities :)  Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little unclear what you want to achieve, but it sounds like you want to have the vertical scrollbar for the page control the scroll position of `#information`.

Unfortunately, using CSS alone, it's not possible to make the scrollbars for the page control the scroll position for an overflow `div`.

However, you can simulate the same effect by allowing `#information` to expand to it's full height (as in your first screenshot) and use elements with `position:fixed` elements to cover portions of `#information`.

Here's a (really simple) **[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/q33qyf71/2/)**.

Your only other option is to apply vertical scroll bars to `#information`:

```
#information{
  height: 400px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FEC12E;

  overflow-y: scroll;

  /* shadow */
  box-shadow: 5px 4px 18px #FEC12E;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I’m glad you understood my question, because it was hard to state clearly and what you said is what I was looking for. Curious, if I can’t make a scrollbar for a page control the scroll position of a div with CSS alone, what else am I supposed to use to achieve that effect?

Comment: @elbertkim Aside from the method I described above (i.e., making the rest of your page `position:fixed` have your content scroll underneath) it's likely possible to wrangle together a hacky JavaScript solution (listen for scroll position change on the `body`, manually adjust scroll position of `#information`, etc), but it would be ugly and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn’t know it could get complicated like that.